# ForEach on a dictionary

Tags: ios, dictionary, object, swiftui, foreach

I need my app to display a table of data. The data looks like `["body": Optional("Go Shopping"), "isDeleted": Optional(false), "_id": Optional("63333b1600ce507b0097e3b3"), "isCompleted": Optional(false)]` The column headers for the table would be the keys `body, isDeleted, isCompleted, _id`. I will have multiple instances of this data that will have the same keys, but different values. I will need to display the values for each data instance under the respective header and each row will belong to one data instance.

Example:

[image]

I'm struggling because the only way I can think of doing this is with a dictionary, but run into a lot of problems when using a dictionary in the View.

*** Important Note:
The app allows a user to select a certain collection and then the app will load all the data for that collection. Each collection has different keys in its data, so I cannot create a specific struct since I won't actually know the keys/values in the data. The model will have to be dynamic in the sense that I don't know what key/value types will be used in each collection and the table will need to redraw when a different collection is selected.

**What I Tried**

A document class that would hold a 'value: [String: Any?]` the string would be the key and the Any is the value from the data instance

```
class Document{
    let value: [String:Any?]
    
    init(value:[String:Any?]) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

in my ViewModel I have a call to a database that uses the selected collection name to return an array of all the documents from that collection. I loop through the array and  create a Document obj with the value of the Document looking like `["body": Optional("Go Shopping"), "isDeleted": Optional(false), "_id": Optional("63333b1600ce507b0097e3b3"), "isCompleted": Optional(false)]` and I add each Document to an array of Document's

```
class DocumentsViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var docKeys: [String]?
    @Published var docsList: [Document]?

    func getDocs() {
       ... //Database call to get docs from collection

            for doc in docs {
                // add doc keys to array (used for table header)
                self.docKeys = doc.value.keys.map{$0}
                
                self.docsList?.append(Document(value: doc.value))
    }
```

Then in my View I tried to first display a header from the docKeys and then use that key to loop through the array of [Document] and access the value var and use the key to get the correct value to display under the header for that document

```
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.collectionName)
        
        HStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.docKeys ?? [], id: \.description) {key in
                Text(key.name)
                VStack {
                    ForEach(viewModel.docsList ?? [], id: \.value) { doc in
                        Text(doc.value[property.name])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After doing research I understand why I can't ForEach over an unsorted dictionary.

I will accept any help/guidance on how I can display this table. Also, if there is any other suggestions besides using a dictionary? THANK YOU!

**Update

I was able to get it working with an ordered collection

```
class Document : Hashable, Equatable{
    static func == (lhs: Document, rhs: Document) -> Bool {
        lhs.id.description == rhs.id.description
    }
    
    let id: String
    let value: OrderedDictionary<String,Any?>
    
    init(id: String, value: OrderedDictionary<String,Any?>) {
        self.id = id
        self.value = value
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
```

Since it is ordered this allowed me to iterate of the dictionary in the View

Comment: do you expect the data in your `Document` values properties to be just String and Bool, or maybe including Int, Double, arrays, custom types etc...?

Comment: Use a custom struct instead to hold the content of a row in a db  table.

Answer (score 0):

Just a a few hints:

- If you need "dictionary with order" you can try to use a `Key-ValuePairs` object which is essentially an array of tuples with labels `key` and `value`
  `let values: KeyValuePairs = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]`
  when you print this to the console you'll realize that this is just a tuple!
  `print(values[0])` will display `(key: "key1", value: "value1")`
- please take a look at `OrderedDictionary` from `The Swift Collections` https://www.kodeco.com/24803770-getting-started-with-the-swift-collections-package
- have you consider to use an array of simple structs instead?

```
struct Document {
  let body: String?
  let isDeleted: Bool?
  let id: String?
  let isCompleted: Bool?
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints! The first point I think could work, but I guess I could lose out on some performance since it's an array and is accessed by index.. As to your last point, I tried explaining (poorly, I imagine) but I can't do a struct like that since the table will need to draw for a variety of collections. Each collection contains different keys so not all of the collections will have a isDeleted, body, etc..