# Unwrap Optional Value from Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swiftui, unwrap

I'm having an issue unwrapping a value thats stored in an Ordered Dictionary. I created a reproducible example.

I'm pulling data from a database and the format looks like `["isCompleted": Optional(false), "_id": Optional("62cef664008fd87e00e60667"), "body": Optional("run")]`

I then create a Document object and store that in a list of those objects (in this sample there is only one).

I'm trying to display the value of the Ordered Dictionary in the Document Object, but can't seem to unwrap the Optional value no matter what I try.

```
import SwiftUI
import OrderedCollections

class ContentViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    var orderedDict = OrderedDictionary<String, Any?>()
    @Published var docsList: [Document] = []

    
    init() {
        let doc: [String: Any?] = ["isCompleted": false, "_id": "62cef664008fd87e00e60667", "body": "run"]
        
        for (key, value) in doc {
            self.orderedDict[key] = value
        }
        
        self.docsList.append(Document(id: UUID().description, value: self.orderedDict))
        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(viewModel.docsList, id: \.self) { doc in
            
            if let val = doc.value["isCompleted"] {
                Text(val.debugDescription)
            }
            
            if(doc.value["isCompleted"] != nil) {
                Text(doc.value["isCompleted"]?.debugDescription ?? "")
            }
            
            Text(doc.value["isCompleted"]?.debugDescription ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import OrderedCollections

class Document : Hashable, Equatable{
    static func == (lhs: Document, rhs: Document) -> Bool {
        lhs.id.description == rhs.id.description
    }
    
    let id: String
    let value: OrderedDictionary<String,Any?>
    
    init(id: String, value: OrderedDictionary<String,Any?>) {
        self.id = id
        self.value = value
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you storing an `Optional(false)`? Why not just store `false`?

Comment: As I said in your previous post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74367026/foreach-on-a-dictionary 
do you expect the data in your Document value properties to be just String and Bool, or could include, Int, Double, arrays, custom types etc...?

Comment: @jnpdx In my app i'm pulling the data from a database and thats how the values are stored. In this code example I'm storing them with Optional(false) cause thats how I receive it from the database.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine It could could be any JSON valid data type

Comment: I assume you mean any custom structs, array of structs etc... that can be JSON decoded, is that correct? Or just the simple swift types. I'm asking because I can see a possible solution for simple types, but not for `any` custom types.

Comment: @texasRanger009 Do you really? My suspicion is that you actually get a `[String: Any?]` -- in this case, you're doubling up the `Optional` by boxing it a second time. My guess is that your test here doesn't reflect the true reality of the situation.

Comment: @jnpdx The doc that I pull down is [String:Any?]?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine just simple swift types

Comment: @texasRanger009 Yep -- exactly what I suspected. You don't need the `Optional(...)` in your test case. It's ready defined as optional on the dictionary type. You're double boxing it

Comment: @jnpdx removed the Optional(), but get the same result. Updated the test code

Comment: `Text(doc.value["isCompleted"] == true ? "true" : "false")`. Or, if you want to account for nil -> `if let isCompleted = doc.value["isCompleted"] as? Bool { Text(isCompleted ? "true" : "false") else { Text("") }`

Comment: Answered your other related question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74367026/foreach-on-a-dictionary/74397937#74397937 . It has relevance to this post.

Comment: @jnpdx Guess I didnt mention this, but the data I'll be using won't all be the same. There wont always be an 'isCompleted', etc.. so I wont be able to cast with as because the data/data types will be changing. You can see more of what I'm trying to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74367026/foreach-on-a-dictionary/74397937#74397937)

Comment: Might be good to read the Swift language book and read about handling optionals -- it should have all the info you need for this: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html